# Remote config value fetching is inconsistent

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, firebase-remote-config

I am fetching Firebase remote config values both in onStart() and in onStop(). The variable I am holding in "min_version", used for in-app updates feature. So my problem is that when I am going to remote config and updating the values, they are not updated immediately but save their old values for one more app lifecycle iteration before being updated to the new value. That means that if I make the decision that I want all users from a certain version to updated, they will not get the in-app update immediately, but only after one iteration through onStop and than get it.

here are my codes for onStart() and onStop() -

```
@Override
  protected void onStart() {
    /**
     * We are fetching the minimum version that we want the user to have from Firebase Remote Config, only after we have the results we can proceed to start the app.
     */
    getMinAppVersion("onStart", () -> {
      // navigation drawer
      checkValidFacebookSession();
      initDrawerMenu();

      // network monitoring
      registerNetworkReceiver();

      // monitoring upload
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mUploadReceiver, new IntentFilter(ULBroadcastConstants.UPLOAD_STATUS_ACTION));
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mFCMReceiver, new IntentFilter(MyFirebaseMessagingService.RECEIVED_FCM_ACTION));

      checkInAppUpdate();
    });
    super.onStart();
  }

@Override
  protected void onStop() {
    getMinAppVersion("onStop", () -> {
      mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(null);
      mDrawerLayout.removeDrawerListener(mBadgeDrawerToggle);


      // network monitor
      unregisterNetworkReceiver();

      // unregister upload
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mUploadReceiver);
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mFCMReceiver);
    });

    super.onStop();
  }
```

here is my 'getMinAppVersion()' method -

```
private void getMinAppVersion(String didComeFrom, OnRemoteConfigFetchComplete listener){
    //fetching the min_version parameter from 'remote config' of Firebase and saves it to our local variable.
    FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
    FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder().setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(200).build();
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings);
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(0);
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activate().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
      if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        min_version = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getLong(RemoteConfigUtil.MIN_VERSION);
        Timber.tag("min_version_" + didComeFrom).d(String.valueOf(min_version));
        if (listener != null)
          listener.onFetchComplete();
      } else {
        Timber.tag("min version").d("error while fetching and activating remove config");
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is why it's happening. The `Remote Config` caches the value in a local storage according to official docs. You can refer here and consider

***"Remote Config includes a client library that handles important tasks like fetching parameter values and caching them, while still giving you control over when new values are activated so that they affect your app's user experience. This lets you safeguard your app experience by controlling the timing of any changes."***

When you use the client library to fetch remote-config parameter, The cached value will be returned to you if it's there(TL;DL) for more information, you can read the official docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config). It uses minimum time interval to fetch the value to avoid app crashes, For that minimum interval time, last fetched value served as a cache

```java
mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
        .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(3600)
        .build();
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings);
```

Here `3600` is time of `minimum interval` between new fetch, You can adjust the time according to your requirement. If you have recently called `fetch()` and once again you are calling it, client-library determines according to `minimum-interval` time that the new API call should be carried out or serve a cached value. Firebase remote config works on REST api and uses [Throttling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android#throttling) as well.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. If you look at the code at my post, I have a minimum interval on 0 milisecs, that should produce a "fcm-like" behaviour, or should it?

Comment: no, It will lead to crash your app if it refreshes to frequent, if you want the setting to be reflected in realtime and quick like fcm, use `realtime database` insted `remote-config`. create a configuration node in the realtime database and your user will always get refreshed values. Because `remote-config` works with restful api and you can consider the `realtime-db` as socket connection like behaviour.

Comment: Alright, so if I understand you correctly the SDK has some crash safetly mechanism that ignores my 0 milisec value and puts it in some minimal allowed value to prevent crashes? because I did not see any crashes at all.

Comment: Yes, because `remote-config` works with a REST API request, If you want realtime behaviour changes in-app, You can use the realtime database instead. Using realtime database as remote-config has no side effects so it worths giving a try.

Comment: Thank you very much. The thing is that the remote config is more user friendly than a giant database. Is there any recommended way to produce a realtime behaviour using remote config?

Comment: No, If you want it realtime, the realtime database will help you. You just have to listen to single node where configurations are stored, database size won't affect you. If you need such implementation I can share a minimal example.

Comment: I know how to do this in realtime database, but thank you for your offer. So I got my answer, thank you very much !

Comment: Check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/propagate-updates-realtime

Answer (score 1):

Remote Config updates in the console are not instant. They don't work like push notifications.  The new values only take effect after the Task returned by [fetch()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.html#fetch(long)) completes, and you call [activate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.html#activate()) after that.  I will point out that you're not using the Task returned by fetch() to find out when the new values have been received from Firebase.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you are suggesing to add some completion listener to the 'fetch()' method? and if so, what should I do with the results?

Comment: If you want to activate the new values immediately after fetch, then call activate inside the success listener for the task it returns.

Comment: Firebase Remote Config also provides a fetchAndActivate() method that encapsulates this behavior: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.html#fetchAndActivate()